# How to align an image to center

Tags: css

I'd like to set the alignment of an image to the center on top of the header. My ERb file is as follows:

```
<p id="logo">
  <%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
</p>
```

In my CSS file, I have:

```
#logo {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  alignment: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

All the CSS code applies except for the alignment. The image still renders to the left of the screen. How can I get the image to align center?

Comment: Align has only one "l" NOt sure if alignment is correct anyway. Maybe text-align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add any styles to your `<p>` element. Instead you should center the `<img>` child element. Also, there is no CSS property named "`alignment`". This block will center your image:

```
#logo > img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Example from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I had to change was add width: 100px; and hight: 100px to set the logo to a fixes size.